# GraphQL: is there an equivalent of TypeScript's "unknown"?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

In GraphQL, I have several queries that support pagination.  The queries take a `cursor` parameter, and return a `nextCursor` parameter.

The type of `cursor/nextCursor` is not important to the consumer.  It could be a `Number` or a `String` or maybe even an object -- it's just an implementation detail that the client should not care about.  Different queries might even use different cursor types.

Is there any way to model this in GraphQL?

In TypeScript, there's an `unknown` type, which basically says "I don't know what type this is, but that's OK, I don't need to know".

Comment: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Types ... what is worth validation to anything? ... use unions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for: a **Custom Scalar**:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/

Example:

```
scalar Cursor
type Query {
  getStrings(count: Int, cursor: Cursor): Result!
}
type Result {
  strings: [String]!
  nextCursor: Cursor
}
```

The custom Scalar type can be anything -- the consumer doesn’t need to know. The server decides how to handle the value (serialize, deserialize, etc).

Comment: similar to ID? ... and [you claim that] FE TS dev (consumer) should use `cursor: any` ... hmmm, where is this famous TS type safety/less error-prone coding? ... I don't think it is *'just an implementation detail that the client should not care about'*

Comment: ... of course, you can use scalar during developing a [general] library ... but for specific 'instance" it should be published what is assumed type (accepted as/validated to) for this scalar (int or string) to give FE devs ability to type-safe coding

Comment: The client should not care about the value. They just receive the cursor from the first query, and pass it along to the next query.

Comment: partially true ... but **all graphql API args should be typed** ... tell this *TSLint with "no-any": true, "no-unsafe-any": true* config users